# Isolated power supply with output on a 2kVDC floating ground

Tags: power-supply, power, ground, floating, isolated

I am building a system of detectors which are referenced to independent floating grounds. The maximum voltage between each stage is 2kVDC. So I need isolated supplies which can operate continuously at this voltage. I found these Mean Well supplies.

RSD-30G-5     VIN: 9-36V VOUT: 5V
RSD-30G-12    VIN: 9-36V VOUT: 12V
Both are 30W

The data sheet reads:

WITHSTAND VOLTAGE 
Input-Output: 4KVDC Input-Frame Ground:2.5KVDC Output-Frame Ground:2.5KVDC

I looked further but I cannot be totally sure the supply wont get shorted in a continuous 2kVDC use. I wanted to know if anyone had a different recommendation regarding the power supply or any thought on using these power supplies at 2kVDC.

I contacted the supplier to clear the rated voltage for continuous operation.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3KgsM.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The maximum voltage a detector can go is 2kVDC.

In [this link](https://www.meanwell.com/webapp/product/search.aspx?prod=RSD-30&pdf=UlNELTMwRy0xMi1ycHQucGRm&a=2) you can find the datasheet and the report of the tests conducted on the device.

Comment: What is the accumulated maximum voltage due to the array of independent floating grounds i.e. do the ground potentials stack up thus for some power supplies you might need 6 kV? Draw a picture.

Comment: Suggest posting a system diagram.  Are they independent sensors?  Or in cascaded stages?  How are they connected.  Also suggest including a link to the datasheet for the device you've mentioned.

Comment: Thanks for your comments I will edit the question.

Comment: You can use Mathjax to better format your posts.

Answer (score 0):

Yes if the DC-DC regulator parts meet the DC HIPOT 2.5kV to earth ground spec (?) the floating cascaded low voltage regulators will work at 2kV output.

Comment: HiPOT tests are not always designed to show long term sustainability at that voltage...

Comment: @MadHatter  true but the difference between short term and long can be as little as 10 or 20% and there is 25% margin. It’s usually the Y. Cap leakage temp rise and frequency of lightning strokes among other component quality factors